# How to find time period in C?

Tags: c, algorithm, datetime

I want to calcute peroid time for turn on/off the light with Arduino. I use hour+minute of time on/off compare with time now. The problem is the time will not correct when set time from AM to PM or PM to AM like this code.

```
// On 23:30
int on_hour = 23;
int on_min = 30;

// Off 08:30
int off_hour = 8;
int off_min = 30;

time_t t = now(); // store the current time in time variable t
hour(t);          // returns the hour for the given time t
minute(t);        // returns the minute for the given time t

int t_now = hour(t)+minute(t); 

int t_on = on_hour + on_min;   //53
int t_off = off_hour + off_min;  //38

//open 23:30 - 08:30
if (t_on > t_off){                  
    if(t_now > t_on)  // if t_now = 01:30 = 31, 31 less than 53 the light will  close
        Serial.printf("open");
    else(if t_now > t_off)    
        Serial.printf("close");
}

//////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////

// On 08:30
on_hour = 8
on_min = 30

// Off 21:30
off_hour = 21
off_min = 30


t_on = on_hour + on_min  // 38
t_off = off_hour + off_min // 51

//open 08:30 - 21:30
if (t_on < t_off){                  
    if(t_now < t_on)  // if t_now = 20:30 = 50, 50 more than 38 the light will  close
        Serial.printf("open");
    else(if t_now > t_off)   
        Serial.printf("close");
}
```

How to fix it?

Comment: Is this `c` or `c++` or [`arduino-c++`](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/arduino-c%2b%2b/info)? Please select a language by tagging the question appropriately.

Comment: maybe `int t_on = on_hour*24 + on_min; // 222` (`t_off` (`21*24 + 30`) would be `534`)

Comment: @AlanBirtles: In your edit, you removed the `c++` tag, leaving only the `c` tag. Are you sure that this was the correct thing to do? I am not familiar with Arduino, but I would guess that lines such as `Serial.printf("open");` would indicate [`arduino-c++`](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/arduino-c%2b%2b/info) instead of C.

Comment: @AndreasWenzel the title says c and i can't see anything requiring c++ in the code. The op is free to change it if they are actually using c++

Answer (score 0):

As you're trying to compare on and off time, use [`time.h`](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man0/time.h.0p.html) library to obtain Unix timestamp of the current time and use that for comparison.

Consider the following example for comparing two times:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <time.h>
#include <unistd.h>

int main(int argc, char* argv[]) {
  time_t begin = -1, end = -1; 
  // Capture begin unix time
  time(&begin);
  // Wait for two seconds
  sleep(2);
  // Capture end unix time
  time(&end);

  if (begin < 0 || end < 0) {
    printf("Error obtaining Unix timestamp.\n");
    exit(1);
  }

  // Comparison operators can now be used
  if (begin < end) {
    printf("Begin timestamp (%lu) is smaller than end timestamp (%lu).\n", begin, end);
  }

  return 0;
}
```

If you need local time for your application, you can use [`ctime`](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/ctime.3p.html) to convert the Unix time to a local time in form of a string.